# shell how to direct all message to file while keeping a handful to screen

Tags: shell, output, stdout, logfile

```
echo start commanda
output=$(commanda soemthing)
echo $output

echo start commandb
output=$(commandb something)
echo $output`
```

How do i do it in shell such that i keep:

```
echo start commanda
echo start commandb
```

in stdout, while keeping:

```
echo start commanda
echo $output
echo start commandb
echo $output
```

in a logfile?

Answer (score 1):

When you want stdout to go to a file, use redirection.  When you want it to go two places, use `tee`:

```
echo start commanda | tee -a logfile
output=$(commanda soemthing)
echo $output >>logfile

echo start commandb | tee -a logfile
output=$(commandb something)
echo $output >>logfile
```

How it works:

- `>>logfile` is called redirection.  It captures stdout and appends it to the file `logfile`.
- `| tee -a logfile` captures the stdout of the previous command, appends a copy to `logfile` and duplicates it again to stdout.  If you want the file to be overwritten rather than appended to, then omit the `-a`.

#### Alternate method

The following sends all output to `logfile`.  Any output line that starts with `start` is also sent to stdout:

```
{
    echo start commanda
    output=$(commanda soemthing)
    echo $output

    echo start commandb
    output=$(commandb something)
    echo $output
} | tee -a logfile | grep '^start'
```

The braces, `{...}`, group the statements together so that we only need redirect for the whole group.  This reduces the number of times that the file `logfile` is opened and closed.  The disadvantage of this approach is that, if the `output` starts with `start`, it will also be sent to stdout.